# Can’t seem to workout how to pass 3 arguments to filter

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am using Jekyll and I have the following filter

```
def localize(input, url, format)
# code
end
```

and I call it within my files as follows:

`{{ 'title' | localize: 'curriculum' }}` and that works fine when I remove the `url` parameter.

Iv tried `{{ 'title', 'url' | localize: 'curriculum' }}` and `{{ 'title' | 'url' | localize: 'curriculum' }}`

but I always get:

`Liquid Exception: wrong number of arguments (2 for 3) in ar-EG/index.html`

Can anyone point out how I can pass in the `url` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter arguments go after the filter, comma separated.

e.g.

```
{{ 'title' | localize: 'curriculum', 'url' }}`
```

Comment: Cheers Dan much appreciated.

Comment: I might be recalling this incorrectly, but from memory, array elements are treated as arguments.  That is, given `{{ 'title' | localie: ['curriculum','foo'], 'url' }}`, 'foo' will unexpectedly be treated as the url.  An alternative would be to make all arguments strings and what you expect to be an array, as a string with delimited values `{{ 'title' | localize: 'curriculum,foo', 'url' }}` then in your filter, `curriculum_array = curriculum_param.split(',') if curriculum_param.is_a? String`